# nodejs connect to server without reloading page

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am maintaning chat application which is built by our company, now the requirement came like, if nodejs server fails and restarted, the user connections who are all connected initially on the load time must be able to connect to socket again but without reloading the page. I am using express for chat. Any answers would be help full for me thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on websocket client library you are using, but the logic is the same across all, try to listen for disconnect event, when the disconnect event is fired for any reasons set an interval and attempt to reconnect until is success or maximum attempts are made and just needs to reload page if necessary by application.